# Prove that the set of points satisfying $x^4-x^2=y^4-y^2=z^4-z^2$ is the union of $4$ straight lines and $6$ ellipses

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Prove that the set of points satisfying $x^4-x^2=y^4-y^2=z^4-z^2$ is the union of $4$ straight lines and $6$ ellipses

i'M new here, and i'm not sure my solution below is right, so could someone give some feedback? that would be nice.

$x^4-x^2=(x^2-1/2)^2-1/4,$ so $x^4-x^2=y^4-y^2$ is equivalent to $(x^2-1/2)^2=(y^2-1/2)^2$ and hence to $x^2-1/2 = \pm (y^2-1/2),$ which is equivalent to $x=\pm y,$ or $x^2+y^2=1.$ Similarly, for $y^4-y^2=z^4-z^2$ is equivalent to $y=\pm z$ or $y^2+z^2=1.$ So the given equation is equivalent to 
$$x=y \wedge y=z,\;(1)$$
$$x=y \wedge y=-z,\;(2)$$
$$x=-y \wedge y=z,\;(3)$$
$$x=-y \wedge y=-z,\;(4)$$
$$x=y \wedge y^2+z^2=1,\;(5)$$
$$x=-y \wedge y^2+z^2=1,\;(6)$$
$$x^2+y^2=1 \wedge y=z,\;(7)$$
$$x^2+y^2=1 \wedge y=-z,\;(8)$$
$$x^2+y^2=1 \wedge y^2+z^2=1,\;(9)$$

Clearly $(1)-(4)$ are straight lines. $(5)$ is the intersection of a plane and a cylinder, which is an ellipse. Similarly, $(6)-(8)$ are also the intersection of a plane and an ellipse. $(9)$ you have to visualize a bit. It is the intersection of two cylinders with the same radius and axes intersecting at right angles to two perpendicular ellipses with a shared minor axis. Otherwise, subtracting the two equations , we see that $x=\pm z$ and the intersection is also given by the intersection of two planes and a cylinder.